# How to space the children of a View Component React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I want a gap of say 30px; between all children of my card (View) component.

```
return (
    <Card style={styles.screen}>
      <Text>...</Text>
      <Text>...</Text>
      <Button title='...' onPress={...} />
    </Card>
  )
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    maxWidth: '80%',
    width: 200,
    paddingVertical: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
})
```

I want all of them to have a space of 30px; between them. How can I do this with React Native's stylesheet?

Comment: Requirnment screenshot if possible !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Card style={styles.screen}>
      <Text style={styles.screenText}>
</Card>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    maxWidth: '80%',
    width: 200,
    paddingVertical: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  screenText: {
    paddingVertical: 30, //just do custom style for each component
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, you're right we can do this but this way is not as good. If I have 100 elements so should I add padding in each component?